# Take a script as input, execute, and test for errors

Tags: bash, scripting

I am trying to make a script that takes the name of a script, executes said script, and then tests it for errors. If errors occurred it will show the errors from the errors.txt file.

```
#!/bin/sh

$scriptName

./$scriptname 2> ~/Documents/LinuxLab3/errors.txt

if [ -s errors.txt ];then
        echo "There were errors:"
        cat ~/Documents/LinuxLab3/errors.txt
else
        echo "No errors encountered"
fi
```

When I run

```
./scriptTester.sh Trial1.sh
```

I get the error

```
./scriptTester.sh: 5: ./scriptTester.sh: ./: Permission denied
```

All the scripts are `sudo chmod +rx`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it wasn't just an error copy-pasting your code, then I see two problems in your code. I assume that your second line should read (to save the argument in a variable)

```
scriptName=$1
```

And then, on your third line, you misspelled the variable - `$scriptname` instead of `$scriptName`.

---

**Update**

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                                                                                                                            

scriptName=$1

./$scriptName 2> errors.txt
```

Comment: Are you sure that you put the `$` symbol? So first, `scriptName=$1` to initialise the variable, then `./$scriptName` to use it?

Comment: 'code' scriptName=$input <br />

./$scriptName 2> ~/Documents/LinuxLab3/errors.txt

Comment: My apologies, I was under the impression that I could use anything for the input. Seems to work now.

Comment: What is the variable `$input`? The first command line argument is always called `$1`, so if you haven't manually put something into `$input` before, it is not going to contain anything... See my updated answer. This code works both on my Mac & Linux machines here. Please copy it exactly, and let me know if it still doesn't work...

Comment: Allright, I see you found the error yourself - happy to help, then :) Please don't forget to accept the answer, if it solved your issue!